# Error when trying to run a project in Eclipse as a Maven test

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium

I am trying to run my maven project in Eclipse as a Maven test but i am getting the following error in the console

> Non-parseable settings
>   /Users/kwo11/Documents/Selenium/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin/m2.conf: only
>   whitespace content allowed before start tag and not s (position:
>   START_DOCUMENT seen s... @1:1)  @
>   /Users/kwo11/Documents/Selenium/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin/m2.conf, line
>   1, column 1

Below is screenshot for the same :

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is content of "/Users/kwo11/Documents/Selenium/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin/m2.conf"?

Comment: The content is in the image in the screenshot. thanks

Comment: Did you copy and paste some text from online to the file? Or this is auto created one?

Comment: It was a while since i downloaded Maven but i cant remember editing this file manually. thank

Comment: Issue has been resolved i must have not installed Maven correctly and unistall and re-install has now got it working